# MITM with forwarding between 2 hosts in the same network

Tags: network, man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing

I have 3 hosts in the same network, let's say their IP addresses end with:

```
.10 (Host A)
.11 (Host B)
.12 (Host C)
```

I want to sniff packets between A and C through host B, so that host B acts as MITM.

I've enabled ip forwarding, so:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

From host B with i perform: `arpspoof -r -i eth0 -t .10 .12`
I am able to see their packets with wireshark so MITM is working but A and C can't communicate because probably the forwarding is not working correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: Always perform a packet capture to see what's actually going on on the wire.

Comment: my fault writing..I've edited thank you. With iptables for A and B forwarding works but only during the first handshake: `iptables -A FORWARD -s IP ip -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -d IP -j ACCEPT.` During communication i don't receive packets...